# Why the plot is not showing the legend

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have problems in showing the legend in a plot. The example code below was taken from matplotlib 3.6 [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/bar_colors.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-bar-colors-py). The plot shows a single color (red) in the legend. I also do not understand what is the role of `bar_labels` in the code. I thank you for any comment.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fruits = ['apple', 'blueberry', 'cherry', 'orange']
counts = [40, 100, 30, 55]
bar_labels = ['red', 'blue', '_red', 'orange']
bar_colors = ['tab:red', 'tab:blue', 'tab:red', 'tab:orange']

ax.bar(fruits, counts, label=bar_labels, color=bar_colors)

ax.set_ylabel('fruit supply')
ax.set_title('Fruit supply by kind and color')
ax.legend(title='Fruit color')

plt.show()
```

Expected figure:

[image]

Got figure:

[image]

Comment: The demo code is from matplotlib 3.6 document. Do you use the same version? In the early version, `label` argument object is treated as a single label for the `BarContainer` returned by `ax.bar()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bar_label consists of the labels (text next to each legend color) for each of the bars. `label=ABC` in your plot tells matplotlib that it should give the name ABC to the label for that color. Also, if there is an underscore (_), matplotlib will ignore that line. So, the label of `red` will be considered, while `_red` will be ignored. In your code, as you are giving each data point individually, you can make this change and it should work. Note that you should probably change the labels of red to apple/cherry, blue to blueberry, etc.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fruits = ['apple', 'blueberry', 'cherry', 'orange']
counts = [40, 100, 30, 55]
bar_labels = ['red', 'blue', '_red', 'orange']
bar_colors = ['tab:red', 'tab:blue', 'tab:red', 'tab:orange']

for i in range(len(fruits)):
    ax.bar(fruits[i], counts[i], color=bar_colors[i], label=bar_labels[i])

ax.set_ylabel('fruit supply')
ax.set_title('Fruit supply by kind and color')
ax.legend(title='Fruit color')
ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: It solved the issue. Many thanks. It is interesting that I took the code from the matplotlib documentation which was not ploting what it was supposed to plot.

Comment: Can you share the link? Also, which version of matplotlib are you running?

Comment: I checked the matplotlib version, it is `3.4.3`. The code I took comes from the first bar plot you will find on https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/index.html.

Comment: Ah ok. Think that works from 3.6 as mentioned by ILS in the comments section for the question. I saw the error as I have `3.3.4`. Upgrading to latest version using `pip install matplotlib` mentioned [here](https://pypi.org/project/matplotlib/) should allow you to make it work

Answer (score 1):

You are probably referring to [matplotlib 3.6 Bar color demo](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/bar_colors.html).
That's working as intended for matplotlib: 3.6.0

However for matplotlib: 3.5.x (see also the OP comment from ILS) that demo functionality isn't implemented. You can change the version at the demo link on the top right to 3.5 and will see that the demo isn't available for that version.

---

To get that going in matplotlib: 3.5.1 you have to assign the plot to a variable to get a `matplotlib.container.BarContainer` which then can be used as `handels` (activate the `print` to see the type).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

fruits = ['apple', 'blueberry', 'cherry', 'orange']
counts = [40, 100, 30, 55]
bar_labels = ['red', 'blue', '_red', 'orange']
bar_colors = ['tab:red', 'tab:blue', 'tab:red', 'tab:orange']

bar_plot =  ax.bar(fruits, counts, label=bar_labels, color=bar_colors)
# print(type(bar))

ax.set_ylabel('fruit supply')
ax.set_title('Fruit supply by kind and color')
ax.legend(handles=bar_plot, labels=bar_labels, title='Fruit color')

plt.show()
```

Notes:

- the `bar_labels` are assigned to `labels` in `ax.legend`

  - that's probably why they were defined in the 1st place
- You may get a user warning wich refers to the matplotlib link above:

  > Note that labels with a preceding underscore won't show up in the
  > legend.

  - that means the 2nd red color from 'cherry' isn't displayed again

    - try to remove the underscore from `'_red'` in `bar_labels` to see the double display

[image]